# Verilog/SV conditional variable definition

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Is there a way to manipulate variable instantiation depending on a parameter?

For example, here if I were to put just `bit [WIDTH-1:0] a;` and set DEPTH == 1, WIDTH would be 0 and `bit [-1:0] a;` would not make sense.

When I code it like in the example below I get an error on the second $display: "Undeclared identifier: a". Is there a way to achieve this in Verilog/SV or is there an error in my code?

```
module test #(
  parameter DEPTH = 2,
  parameter WIDTH = $clog2(DEPTH)
)();

  generate
    if (WIDTH == 0) begin
      bit             a;
    end else begin
      bit [WIDTH-1:0] a;
    end
  endgenerate

  initial begin
    $display("WIDTH: %d", WIDTH);
    $display("Bit width of a: %d", $bits(a));
  end
endmodule: test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
bit [(WIDTH>0 ? WIDTH-1 : 0):0] a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Verilog are you using?  $clog2 was introduced in Verilog-2005.  Prior implementations, can give odd results.

See below, I did a loop to show incrementing depth versus result of clog2.

```
CLOG2(0) =           0
CLOG2(1) =           0
CLOG2(2) =           1
CLOG2(3) =           2
CLOG2(4) =           2
```

To represent the value of 1, for instance, you need 1 bit, not 0
To represent the value of 2, you need 2 bits...not 1.
To represent the value of 4, you need 3 bits.  CLOG2 is always 1 short at the transition points.  The prior solution will not account for that as you grow.

So if you say

```
WIDTH = $clog(DEPTH+1);
```

I think you will automatically get the results you want.

Comment: I'm using SystemVerilog. Unfortunately, I want the result of CLOG2(1) and CLOG2(2) to be both 1, so this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I made & use this on a regular basis. It determines the width in bits of an integer value.  Special case of 0 will return a value of 1 (you still need 1 bit to hold the value).  Let's say you need to define an index variable based on memory that has 256 addresses

parameter NUM_ADDR 256

localparam A_SZ = bit_size(NUM_ADDR-1);  // example: 255 (highest address) should return 8

logic [A_SZ-1:0] index; // example: [7:0] index

Then All I ever need to change is NUM_ADDR

```
function integer bit_size;
input integer value;
reg [31:0] shifted;
integer res;
begin
  if (value != 0)
  begin
       shifted = value;
       for (res=0; (shifted != 0); res=res+1)
           shifted = shifted >> 1;
       bit_size = res;
  end
  else
     bit_size = 1; // minimum size, even for a value of 0
end
endfunction
```